# Regex to match entries between slashes, but not slashes - including empty entries

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use a regexp to match entries between the slashes in the text below:

```
311102Z/5663.00N/00813.02E/GPS//03/-/
```

For this example, the results should be a series of matches which have the content:

- `311102Z`
- `5663.00N`
- `00813.02E`
- `GPS`
- (an empty string)
- `03`
- `-`

It is important that we catch the empty entry and return an empty match. Unfortunately, for various reasons, we can't use grouping here, or match the slashes themselves and split on those.

I have the following regex as something that is almost working: `(.*?)(?=/)`. An interactive display of this regex can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/AGMfuk/1). It matches all the entries fine, but has extra empty matches at the end of each entry.

I tried replacing the `*` with a `+`, but of course that meant that it didn't match the blank entry.

Does anyone have any ideas what I could do to make it match the way I want to - ie. *without* these extra empty matches, but *with* the empty entry in the position where there are no characters between the slashes.

If it matters for compatibility, I'm using this regex in Python.

Comment: Why do you need to use a regex? It sounds like you could just use `str.split("/")`?

Comment: You can just use `([^/]*)/` as regex see demo: https://regex101.com/r/AGMfuk/2

Comment: @PeterH. Unfortunately for compatibility with the rest of the system, we need to use a regex for this - as all other lines this code has to deal with require a regex to split.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, but unfortunately we need to have the *full match* matching without the slash at the end, again due to some other requirements of the system we can't just select the first group. By 'full match' here I mean each of the matches in my bullet point list needs to be the full content of the match, not the content of a group within the match.

Comment: Would `lst = s[:-1].split('/')` help? Where `s` is your string?

Comment: This question sounds like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Ruzihm, I don't see why. The OP has stated the problem clearly without reference to an approach that should be taken.

Comment: @CarySwoveland using a regex is the assumed approach for a vague "compatibility".

Answer (score 4):

You may use this regex with lookahead and lookbehind assertions:

```
(?:(?<=/)|^)[^/]*(?=/)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AGMfuk/4)

**Code:**

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '311002Z/3623.00N/00412.02E/GPS//03/-/'
>>> print (re.findall(r'(?:(?<=/)|^)[^/]*(?=/)', s))
['311002Z', '3623.00N', '00412.02E', 'GPS', '', '03', '-']
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:(?<=/)|^)`: Lookbehind to assert that we have either start or `/` at previous position
- `[^/]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `/`
- `(?=/)`: Lookahead to assert that we have a `/` ahead

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you could match 1+ times any char except `/`, asserting a `/` on the right.

Or get the position between 2 forward slashes.

```
[^/]+(?=/)|(?<=/)(?=/)
```

*Explanation*

- `[^/]+(?=/)` Match 1+ times any char except `/` and assert a `/` at the right
- `|` Or
- `(?<=/)(?=/)` Get the position between 2 forward slashes

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NjG8f3/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/4RsyYS)

Example code

```
import re
 
s="311102Z/5663.00N/00813.02E/GPS//03/-/"
pattern = r"[^/]+(?=/)|(?<=/)(?=/)"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
'311102Z', '5663.00N', '00813.02E', 'GPS', '', '03', '-']
```

Answer (score 1):

One more (Python):

```
(?<=/)(?=/)|[^/]+
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/wuhYAo/2/)

```
(?<=/)  : use a positive lookbehind to assert match is preceded by '/'
(?=/)   : use a positive lookahead to assert match is followed by '/'
|       : or
[^/]+   : match 1+ characters other than '/'
```

Change `[^/]+` to `[^/\n]+` to prevent matches from spanning line terminators.

Comment: Hi, I posted a question today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62607380/how-to-do-user-inputted-string-templating-in-ruby , If you know any new way to solve the problem, can you post there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split` for this (same as `str.split`, only using a regex), then removing the last item:

```
>>> import re
>>> foo = "311102Z/5663.00N/00813.02E/GPS//03/-/"

>>> re.split("/", foo)[:1]
['311102Z', '5663.00N', '00813.02E', 'GPS', '', '03', '-']
```

Comment: This was my first suggestion to OP in comments but unfortunately OP cannot use capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

Then i would suggest:

```
import re
 
entry = "311102Z/5663.00N/00813.02E/GPS//03/-/" 
  
match = re.findall("([^/]*)/", entry)  
print(match)
```

which returns

```
['311102Z', '5663.00N', '00813.02E', 'GPS', '', '03', '-']
```

Comment: This was my first suggestion to OP in comments but unfortunately OP cannot use capture groups.

Comment: It sounds like OP has a problematic codebase then :)