# How to do user-inputted string templating in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I know writing like

```
a=23
p "the value of a is #{a}"
```

it will print: `the value of a is 23`.

but now I am actually receiving this string as a parameter like

```
def evaluate string
  a=23
  puts string
end
```

calling method pass that string as a parameter

```
evaluate "the value of a is #{a}"
```

Is there any way to evaluate this string inside the method? `puts string` has to interpolate the value a=23.

**Edit:**

I have to read and execute the program from Excel.

At the first line,

Excel entry is,

```
"id=something" setvalue a
```

So now corresponding program will read the value from locator id=something and set it into the instance variable @a.

and user's next excel entry would be

```
"the value of a is 23"  compare "the value of a is #{a}"
```

Now the program will read "the value of a is 23" and this "the value of a is #{a}" for comparison, but before it compares, it has to replace the value a. That's all I want. I hope now my question is very clear.

Comment: You can't be receiving `"the value of a is #{a}"` without having defined `a` previously, since that would raise a NameError exception. Have you checked that?

Comment: I can receive that as a string. I am reading the string from Excel and executing it in my program, so I receive `the value of a is #{a}` as the string, so it would not throw any error.

Comment: FYI, if you want to do exactly that, you'd have to allow executing user input code, which would be introducing an injection attack vector. See my answer for some more info.

Comment: @Kache I have detailed it now in my question, can you refer it ?

Comment: I can't offer any suggestions that are not covered [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-ruby-way/0768667208/0768667208_ch02lev1sec22.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ruby you can change how you "format" your strings in Excel, than you can use "classic" formatting

```
a = 23
s = 'the value of a is %s'

def evaluate(text, value)
  puts text % value
end
```

You can use different formatting keys, for example `%d` for integers, `%f` for float numbers

You can use named arguments

```
dynamic_text = 'the value of the %<product_name>s is %<product_price>0.2f'

def evaluate(text, args)
  puts text % args
end

name = "Product"
price = 78.99
evaluate dynamic_text, product_name: name, product_price: price
```

Without names, use order of the given values

```
dynamic_text = 'the value of the %s is %0.2f'

def evaluate(text, args)
  puts text % args
end

name = "Product"
price = 78.99
evaluate dynamic_text, [name, price]
```

Comment: The user will be giving this string in Excel `'the value of a is %s'` and also they would be setting the value of a from excel. I have written a code to set the value of a by using `instance_variable_set` But now using your code, he has to give the variable name inside the string. But that's not the case in your code.

Comment: User don't need to give variable name, variable name can be anything. With named arguments you just need to match hash given to the method `evaluate` and names used in the dynamic string.

Comment: @Rajagopalan, If users will be setting values in excel you just need to "convert" values in excel to the hash { value_name: name } and pass it to the `evaluate` method

Comment: Nope. It's hard to explain to you. But thanks for you try!

Comment: @Rajagopalan, Can you show how you are getting values from the excel? Because, if users set values in excel they need to name that values somehow. If they put a name for value, then you can convert it to hash. If they put values without names, then they probably use an order of values as a way to recognise which value is what. In that case you can convert values into an array and pass it to he evaluate method - and it works

Comment: Your answer really helped me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a block and then evaluate the string:

```
def evaluate &block
  a=23
  block.call(a)
end

evaluate { |a| "the value of a is #{a}" } #=> "the value of a is 23"
```

Comment: no no! This string `the value of a is #{a}` is dynamic, for an example, next time I may receive something like `Plan #{a} Issued`

Answer (score 1):

It's a very odd thing you're attempting to do. When you have some sort of a pattern with placeholders, you do it like:

```
def evaluate(string)
  a=23
  format string, a: a
end

evaluate "the value of a is %{a}"
```

String interpolation with `#{..}` is not meant for the case you're describing as the value is evaluated at the time of constructing the string, not later. You could do some regexp matching and replace the `#{..}` with `%{..}` as a workaround.

Comment: `Kernel#format` is tolerant to supplying more interpolation params than the string actually has, e.g `format "the value of a is %{b}", a: '23, b: 42`. I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: If it's only one variable or the order of the params is the same as they appear in the string, then https://stackoverflow.com/a/62607973/1205724 is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways:

## "Code" Dynamic

lazy evaluation with lambdas:

```rb
def evaluate(str_template)
  a = 23
  str_template.call(a)
end

user_input = gets
my_lambda = lambda do |str|
  user_input.size > 10 ? "dynamic 1 #{str}" : "dynamic 2 #{str}"
end
evaluate(my_lambda)
# => "dynamic 1/2 23"
```

This is "code dynamic", but not "input dynamic", i.e. you can't receive the string template from the user.

## "Input" Dynamic 1

ERB templating:

```rb
require 'erb'

user_input_erb = gets
puts user_input_erb # "Hello <%= name %>"

name = gets # also user input, e.g. "World"

ERB.new(user_input_erb).result
# => "Hello World"
```

Note that in general, getting string templates from the user and evaluating them is a potential security vulnerability. If there's any possibility user input can be adversarial, you'll want to see if you can find a "guaranteed to be safe against all user input" string templating library.

## "Input" Dynamic 2

```rb
user_input_template = gets
puts user_input_template # "Hello %s"

name = gets # also user input, e.g. "World"

user_input_template % name
# => "Hello World"
```

## "Input" Dynamic 3

Really dangerous, but:

```
user_input_ruby_code = gets
puts user_input_ruby_code # '"Hello #{name}"'

name = gets # also user input, e.g. "World"

eval user_input_ruby_code # DANGER
# => "Hello World"
```

Comment: I am saying `"blah blah #{str}"` is dynamic! Then how come it works? yes it's code dynamic ~

Comment: Are you looking to receive a string template from the user? There's more than one way to be dynamic, you should clarify.

Comment: user first the set the value of a and then User will give the input string in the Excel like `the value of a is #{a}` .

Comment: Updated to add an "Input" dynamic example. NOTE: this version requires trusting user input.